# Gradient error when calculating - pytorch

Tags: numpy, graph, neural-network, pytorch

I am learning to use pytorch (0.4.0) to automate the gradient calculation, however I did not quite understand how to use the backward () and grad, as I'm doing an exercise I need to calculate df / dw using pytorch and
 making the derivative analytically, returning respectively auto_grad, user_grad, but I did not quite understand the use of automatic differentiation, in the code I made f.backward () and did w.grad to find df / dw, in addition the two calculations are not corresponding, if I even erred the derivative, it follows the graph that I am using and the code that I am trying to do:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

def graph2(W_np, x_np, b_np):
    W = torch.Tensor(W_np)
    W.requires_grad = True
    x = torch.Tensor(x_np)
    b = torch.Tensor(b_np)
    u = torch.matmul(W, x) + b
    g = F.sigmoid(u)
    f = torch.sum(g)
    user_grad = (sigmoid(W_np*x_np + b_np)*(1 - sigmoid(W_np*x_np + b_np))).T*x_np
    f.backward(retain_graph=True)
    auto_grad = W.grad

    print(auto_grad) 
    print(user_grad)



 #   raise NotImplementedError("falta completar a função graph2")
    # END YOUR CODE
    return f, auto_grad, user_grad
```

test:

```
iterations = 1000
sizes = np.random.randint(2,10, size=(iterations))
for i in range(iterations):
    size = sizes[i]
    W_np = np.random.rand(size, size)
    x_np = np.random.rand(size, 1)
    b_np = np.random.rand(size, 1)
    f, auto_grad, user_grad = graph2(W_np, x_np, b_np)
    manual_f = np.sum(sigmoid(np.matmul(W_np, x_np) + b_np))
    assert np.isclose(f.data.numpy(), manual_f, atol=1e-4), "f not correct"
    assert np.allclose(auto_grad.numpy(), user_grad), "Gradient not correct"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you computed the gradients in the wrong way. Try this.

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x))

def graph2(W_np, x_np, b_np):
    W = Variable(torch.Tensor(W_np), requires_grad=True)
    x = torch.tensor(x_np, requires_grad=True).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    b = torch.tensor(b_np, requires_grad=True).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    u = torch.matmul(W, x) + b
    g = F.sigmoid(u)
    f = torch.sum(g)
    user_grad = (sigmoid(np.matmul(W_np, x_np) + b_np)*(1 - sigmoid(np.matmul(W_np, x_np) + b_np)))*x_np.T
    f.backward(retain_graph=True)
    auto_grad = W.grad
    print("auto_grad", auto_grad) 
    print("user_grad", user_grad)
    # END YOUR CODE
    return f, auto_grad, user_grad




iterations = 1000
sizes = np.random.randint(2,10, size=(iterations))
for i in range(iterations):
    size = sizes[i]
    print("i, size", i, size)
    W_np = np.random.rand(size, size)
    x_np = np.random.rand(size, 1)
    b_np = np.random.rand(size, 1)
    f, auto_grad, user_grad = graph2(W_np, x_np, b_np)
    manual_f = np.sum(sigmoid(np.matmul(W_np, x_np) + b_np))
    assert np.isclose(f.data.numpy(), manual_f, atol=1e-4), "f not correct"
    assert np.allclose(auto_grad.numpy(), user_grad), "Gradient not correct"
```